# Reason to use rsyslog for log rotating?

Tags: logrotate, rsyslog

Is there any benefit to using rsyslog's rotation abilities over the standard /sbin/logrotate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that if you're *already* using logrotate, there's no reason to switch.  In particular, since logrotate will handle log rotation for things other than syslog (e.g., Apache logfiles), this lets you configure your log rotation policies in one location rather than having to create per-application rotation policies.